# PyTorch: Different Forward Methods for Train and Test/Validation

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch, transformer-model, seq2seq

I'm currently trying to extend [a model](https://github.com/microsoft/MASS) that is based on FairSeq/PyTorch. During training I need to train two encoders: one with the target sample, and the original one with the source sample.

So the current forward function looks like this:

```
def forward(self, src_tokens=None, src_lengths=None, prev_output_tokens=None, **kwargs):
    encoder_out = self.encoder(src_tokens, src_lengths=src_lengths, **kwargs)
    decoder_out = self.decoder(prev_output_tokens, encoder_out=encoder_out, **kwargs)
    return decoder_out
```

And based on this [this idea](https://github.com/golsun/SpaceFusion) i want something like this:

```
def forward_test(self, src_tokens=None, src_lengths=None, prev_output_tokens=None, **kwargs):
    encoder_out = self.encoder(src_tokens, src_lengths=src_lengths, **kwargs)
    decoder_out = self.decoder(prev_output_tokens, encoder_out=encoder_out, **kwargs)
    return decoder_out

def forward_train(self, src_tokens=None, src_lengths=None, prev_output_tokens=None, **kwargs):
    encoder_out = self.encoder(src_tokens, src_lengths=src_lengths, **kwargs)
    autoencoder_out = self.encoder(tgt_tokens, src_lengths=src_lengths, **kwargs)
    concat = some_concatination_func(encoder_out, autoencoder_out)
    decoder_out = self.decoder(prev_output_tokens, encoder_out=concat, **kwargs)
    return decoder_out
```

Is there any way to do this?

Edit:
These are the constraints that I have, since I need to extend *FairseqEncoderDecoderModel*:

```
@register_model('transformer_mass')
class TransformerMASSModel(FairseqEncoderDecoderModel):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder):
        super().__init__(encoder, decoder)
```

Edit 2:
The parameters passed to the forward function in Fairseq can be altered by implementing your own Criterion, see for example [CrossEntropyCriterion](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/fairseq/criterions/cross_entropy.py#L28), where `sample['net_input']` is passed to the `__call__` function of the model, which invokes the `forward` method.

Comment: I don't see what the question is. Just put the 2 forward functions in your model class. Then, while training, use `model.forward_train` on the input. And while testing use `model.forward_test` on the input. Note that you can't do `model(input)` in that case since PyTorch considers that equivalent to `model.forward(input)`, so that would throw an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all you should **always use and define `forward`** not some other methods that you call on the `torch.nn.Module` instance.

**Definitely do not overload `eval()` as shown by [trsvchn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58659193/10886420) as it's evaluation method defined by PyTorch ([see here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.eval)).** This method allows layers inside your model to be put into evaluation mode (e.g. specific changes to layers like inference mode for `Dropout` or `BatchNorm`).

Furthermore you should call it with `__call__` magic method. Why? Because hooks and other PyTorch specific stuff is registered that way properly.

**Secondly, do not use some external `mode` string variable as suggested by [@Anant Mittal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58655207/pytorch-different-forward-methods-for-train-and-test-validation/58655415#58655415)**. That's what `train` variable in PyTorch is for, it's standard to differentiate by it whether model is in `eval` mode or `train` mode.

That being said you are the best off doing it like this:

```
import torch


class Network(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...

    # You could split it into two functions but both should be called by forward
    def forward(
        self, src_tokens=None, src_lengths=None, prev_output_tokens=None, **kwargs
    ):
        encoder_out = self.encoder(src_tokens, src_lengths=src_lengths, **kwargs)
        if self.training:
            return self.decoder(prev_output_tokens, encoder_out=encoder_out, **kwargs)
        autoencoder_out = self.encoder(tgt_tokens, src_lengths=src_lengths, **kwargs)
        concat = some_concatination_func(encoder_out, autoencoder_out)
        return self.decoder(prev_output_tokens, encoder_out=concat, **kwargs)
```

You could (and arguably should) split the above into two separate methods, but that's not too bad as the function is rather short and readable that way. Just stick to PyTorch's way of handling things if easily possible and not some ad-hoc solutions. And no, there will be no problem with backpropagation, why would there be one?

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right, my bad -- `eval` is reserved, I have to change it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Szymon Maszke, I wasn't aware of  this variable. I just thought logically and just came up with a way so that only forward function has to be wriitten. But thanks a lot.

Comment: @Szymon Maszke Thanks a lot for the answer! The train variable is very helpful. I'm not sure however on how to pass the target tokens to the forward method, since I train with the fairseq-train command, that only passes the source tokens.

Comment: @qwertz I'm not sure I follow. You can pass any variables to either `forward` or `__init__` at least if you don't want to export the code with JIT. And what is `fair-seq` train command? Could you provide an example and link to some source? How is it different from standard PyTorch?

Comment: @Szymon Maszke I'm implementing the class "FairseqEncoderDecoderModel" from the Fairseq framework. https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/fairseq/models/fairseq_model.py#L184 And I train using this command: https://fairseq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line_tools.html#fairseq-train So I do not actually handle the data loading myself and do not know where the forward method is ultimately called by the fairseq-train cmd command.

Comment: Can't help you either unfortunately

Comment: `self.train` attribute doesn't work for me. I have to use `self.training` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

By default, calling `model()` invoke `forward` method which is train forward in your case, so you just need to define new method for your test/eval path inside your model class, smth like here:

Code:

```py
class FooBar(nn.Module):
    """Dummy Net for testing/debugging.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...

    def forward(self, x):
        # here will be train forward
        ...

    def evaltest(self, x):
        # here will be eval/test forward
        ...
```

Examples:

```py
model = FooBar()  # initialize model 

# train time
pred = model(x)   # calls forward() method under the hood

# test/eval time
test_pred = model.evaltest(x)
```

**Comment:**
I would like to recommend you to split these two forward paths into 2 separate methods, because it easier to debug and to avoid some possible problems when backpropagating.